# Differences between AcquireTokenAsync and LoginAsync in Xamarin Native

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin.ios, active-directory, azure-mobile-services

#### TL;DR

What is the difference between authenticating users with `AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync()` and `MobileServiceClient.LoginAsync()` ?
Can I use the token from the first method to authenticate a user in the second?

#### Long Version

I've been trying to authenticate users via a **mobile device** (iOS) for a **mobile service** in **Azure** with **Xamarin Native** (not Forms).

*There are enough tutorials online to get you started but in the process, I got lost and confused...*

What's working at the moment is the following; which has the user enter his credentials in another page and returns a JWT token which (if decoded [here<sup>1</sup>](https://jwt.io/)) has the claims listed [here<sup>2</sup>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-token-and-claims).

Moreover, this token is authorized in controllers with the `[Authorize]` attribute in requests with an `Authorization` header and a `Bearer token`.

**Note**: the following constants are taken from the registered applications in Active Directory (*Native* and *Web App / API*).

```cs
public const string Authority = @"https://login.windows.net/******.com";
public const string GraphResource = @"https://*******.azurewebsites.net/********";
public const string ClientId = "046b****-****-****-****-********0290";
public const string Resource = @"https://******.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/done";

var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority);
if (authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().Any(c => c.Authority == Authority))
{
    authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().First().Authority);
}

var uri = new Uri(Resource);
var platformParams = new PlatformParameters(UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController);
AuthenticationResult authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(GraphResource, ClientId, uri, platformParams);
```

Another working authentication flow I tried is the following; which does the same with the difference that it informs the user that the app requires permissions to access some resources.

If allowed, a JWT token (with less characters than the previous one) is returned with less payload data. This token though, **won't pass the authorization** attribute just like the previous one.

```cs
public const string AadResource = @"https://******.azurewebsites.net/.auth/aad";

var client = new MobileServiceClient(AadResource);
var rootView = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController;
MobileServiceUser user = await client.LoginAsync(rootView, "aad");
```

Obviously, the return type is different, but, **what is the main difference between these two authentication methods**?

**Additionally**, another headache comes from trying to achieve [this<sup>3</sup>](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter2/enterprise/) at the very end of the article. I already have the token from the first aforementioned method but when I try to follow the client flow with the token in `client.LoginAsync()` the following error is returned:

> **The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.**

#### Link References:

1. https://jwt.io/
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-token-and-claims
3. https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter2/enterprise/
4. https://www.reddit.com/r/xamarindevelopers/comments/6dw928/differences_between_acquiretokenasync/

#### Edit (30 May 2017)

The `Why are they different?` has been answered on [this<sup>4</sup>](https://www.reddit.com/r/xamarindevelopers/comments/6dw928/differences_between_acquiretokenasync/) reddit post by the same person (*pdx mobilist* / *saltydogdev*) and the simple answer is `claims`.

Comment: The difference between the two tokens could be the claims. Have you unpacked them to see what the underlying tokens look like?

Comment: Yes! Claims it is. What I don't get though is why there are 2 authentication methods - one requires user acceptance, the other a simple login. Are there any pros and cons and scenarios when should I use each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can insert a token into the MobileServicesClient and then use it had been authenticated directly. That's the beauty of bearer tokens.

Just set the MobileServiceClient CurrentUser:

```
MobileServiceclient Client;
...
Client.CurrentUser = new MobileServiceUser(username) 
       { MobileServiceAuthenticationToken = authtoken};
```

Edit:

The reason they are different is because each library is requesting a different set of claims. The reason they still work is that the basic information for authenticating/validating the token is there. I'm not sure what are the specific required claims. At a minimum it would be the user id AND that the signature is valid. They are doing the same basic thing, MobileServiceClient just requests less claims.

I believe that the MobileServicesClient can authenticate against Azure AD, if you set up the mobile service correctly. So you should be able to just use the MobileServiceClient.

Here is the document that describes how this works: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-active-directory-authentication